# Plot state provinces around map colored by German zip codes

Tags: r, maps, shapefile, r-sf, tmap

I'm trying to create a map, where I color by German zip codes and I would like to add German states as boundaries.

```
# for loading our data
library(raster)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# for datasets
library(maps)
library(spData)

# for plotting
library(grid)
library(tmap)
library(viridis)
```

Get shape files for Germany ([link](https://opendata-esri-de.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5b203df4357844c8a6715d7d411a8341_0/explore?location=51.099785%2C10.454062%2C7.47)). In Germany zip codes are called Postleitzahlen (PLZ).

```
germany <- read_sf("data/OSM_PLZ.shp")
```

Classify PLZs into arbitrary groups for plotting.

```
germany <- germany %>% 
  mutate(plz_groups = case_when(
    substr(plz, 1, 1) == "1" ~ "Group A",
    substr(plz, 2, 2) == "2" ~ "Group B",    
    TRUE ~ "Group X" # rest
  ))
```

Make plot filling by PLZ:

```
tm_shape(germany) +
  tm_fill(col = "plz_groups")
```

[image]

Try to plot the boundaries of the German states ("Bundesland") on top:

```
tm_shape(germany) +
  tm_fill(col = "plz_groups") +
  tm_borders(col = "bundesland")
```

**Error in col2rgb(col, alpha = TRUE) : ungültiger Farbname in 'bundesland'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw the boundaries of the German states on top you first have to get a shape file for the German states, e.g. from [ESRI](https://opendata-esri-de.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/esri-de-content::bundesl%C3%A4ndergrenzen-2018/explore?location=50.910218%2C10.454033%2C7.00). Afterwards you could add that shape file via `tm_shape` and draw the boundaries via `tm_borders`  where the `col` argument is used to set the color for the border lines. From the docs:

> For tm_borders, it is a single color value that specifies the border line color.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

germany <- read_sf("Postleitzahlengebiete_-_OSM/OSM_PLZ.shp")

german_states <- read_sf("Bundesl%C3%A4ndergrenzen_2018/Bundesländergrenzen_2018.shp")

germany <- germany %>%
  mutate(plz_groups = case_when(
    substr(plz, 1, 1) == "1" ~ "Group A",
    substr(plz, 2, 2) == "2" ~ "Group B",
    TRUE ~ "Group X" # rest
  ))

tm_shape(germany) +
  tm_fill(col = "plz_groups") +
  tm_shape(german_states) +
  tm_borders(col = "black")
```

[image]